# How to adjust height of material UI header with styles

Tags: javascript, material-ui

How can you style the header of a MUI table like height and width?

```
<TableHead >
  <TableRow >
    <TableCell hover>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
</TableHead>
```

I tried passing
`sx={{ height:'20px'  }}`
but the height is fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using sx on the TableHead component:

```
<TableHead sx={{height:"150px"}}>
        <TableRow >
            <TableCell hover>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
 </TableHead>
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the styling of the `TableHead` you need to target the **`MuiTableCell-head`** class of the `Table`.

One important thing to notice, Mui `TableHead` height is not coming from the `height` property, It is coming from **`line-height`**. Please check the example below:

```
 import { Table, TableHead, TableBody } from '@mui/material'


 <Table sx={{ '& .MuiTableCell-head':{ lineHeight: 20, color: 'red' } }}>

      <TableHead>
      </TableHead>

      <TableBody>
      </TableBody>

  </Table>
```